# Did Christine Ford testify both that she drank alcohol and didn't drink alcohol at the party where she was assaulted?

Tags: united-states, alcohol

According to [Yahoo!](https://www.yahoo.com/news/christine-ford-tells-senate-she-105029392.html) and [The Independent](https://www.independent.co.uk/news/world/americas/us-politics/christine-ford-brett-kavanaugh-rape-kill-feinstein-senate-hearing-testimony-a8558011.html):

Ford testified that:

> I did not want to tell my parents that **I**, at age 15, was in a house without any parents present, **drinking beer with boys**.

but the article also says:

> Ms Ford was asked if she had been drinking that night.
>
> “Not at all,” she said.

Is it true that she testified that she was drinking beer with boys and that she was not drinking?

Comment: @DavePhD: Note that document is not really a "transcript"; it is written testimony that Ford (apparently) submitted in advance of the Sep. 27 hearing.  (You'll observe it is dated Sep. 26.)  I don't know whether she read that statement verbatim at the hearing.

Comment: @NateEldredge https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/national/wp/2018/09/27/kavanaugh-hearing-transcript/?noredirect=on&utm_term=.04e16d29453c

Answer (score 23):

No, when she said "Not at all" she was answering the question:

> Do you recall prior to getting there — so I’m — I’m only talking about up to the gathering — had you had anything to drink?

According to a [full transcript](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/national/wp/2018/09/27/kavanaugh-hearing-transcript/?noredirect=on&utm_term=.04e16d29453c).